# C# Statement Textboxes Sum

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to sum the values from 3 textboxes with the following statement, however i cant seem to get it working. The 3 textboxes have values displayed decimal. Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
        decimal num1, num2, num3, total;
        num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(SSubTotalTextBox.Text);
        num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(SubTotalMTextBox.Text);
        num3 = Convert.ToDecimal(SubTotalTextBox3.Text);
        total = num1 + num2 + num3;
        TotalAmountTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Can you give an example content of one of the textboxes?

Comment: So what's the format you are using? Do you type: "23,11" or "23.11"?

Comment: Oh i expect TotalAmountTextBox.Text to display the result of the sum of the 3 Textboxes, SSubTotalTextBox, SubTotalMTextBox and SubTotalTextBox3

Comment: What Forlan07 is refering to is your locale settings. Do you use a , (comma) or . (dot) for the decimal seperator?

Comment: Please give us an example content of one of those textboses...

Comment: @pacheco - It seems you have a $ inside each of the textboxes? See my updated answer, and see if it helps you out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It not enough details in the question, but my gut feeling tells me this is the problem:

You have the content in the textbox like **40,5**, but the computers current culture has the decimal seperator set to **.(dot)**. Therefore you get an exception while converting 40,5 to a decimal, since it does not understand ,.

It could be the other way around and you are writing 40.5, but it expect to get 40.5.

**EDIT**

I saw the comment on *Florian von Spiczak* answer, and it seems that the character $ is present in the textboxes. If it is, that is obviously a problem.

Try to replace all the `textBox.Text` inside the `Convert.ToDecimal` calls with `textBox.Text.Replace("$","")`. That should get rid of the $ and make it parse properly.

So the complete code should then be:

```
decimal num1, num2, num3, total;
num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(SSubTotalTextBox.Text.Replace("$",""));
num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(SubTotalMTextBox.Text.Replace("$",""));
num3 = Convert.ToDecimal(SubTotalTextBox3.Text.Replace("$",""));
total = num1 + num2 + num3;
TotalAmountTextBox.Text = "$ "+ total;
```

Also, you should replace `Convert.ToDecimal` with `decimal.Parse` or `decimal.TryParse`, and add some validation logic on what is actually written inside your textboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Convert.ToDecimal try:

```
 decimal dec1;
 if (!Decimal.TryParse(SSubTotalTextBox.Text, dec1)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Error trying to convert to a decimal: " + SSubTotalTextBox.Text);
 }
```

That should help you find out what's wrong with the input of your textboxes.

Answer (score 2):

the best way is to use decimal.TryParse() method, then you could do some validations.
MSDN: [Decimal.TryParse Method (String, Decimal)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Did you enter values in all textboxes? Convert may not like empty strings. You can also try decimal.Parse or decimal.TryParse instead of Convert.

Edit: I don't think that culture is a problem, yet. Even if it's entered with 6,4 and the culture expects 6.4 the , will usually be interpretet as thousand seperator and would result in 64 instead of 6.4.

Comment: tried decimal.Parse but to no avail. if i change 'decimal' to 'string' my total text box seems to get the string of the 3 values I.E $5.00 + $10.00 + $30.00 but it doesn't sum the 3 values.

Comment: @pacheco Well, you're trying to convert a "$5.00" string to a decimal. That won't work. Instead, see what property of the textbox object (SSubTotalTextBox.Value ?) gives you the value of the input, instead of the text which also holds the "$" sign.

Comment: did you try it like this? ` decimal num1, num2, num3, total;
        decimal.TryParse(SSubTotalTextBox.Text, out num1);
        decimal.TryParse(SubTotalMTextBox.Text, out num2);
        decimal.TryParse(SubTotalTextBox.Text, out num3);
        total = num1 + num2 + num3;
        TotalAmountTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
`

Comment: ignored the $ ... doh
Either remove the curreny sign or you could use the advanced overload of tryparse, there you can exactly specify what is allowed and in which cultrue:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx

Comment: Ok thanks all, I need this to insert the value in a table. But, yes I agree that some validations need to be done