# C#.net how to Get SUM of numbers entered in textbox array. which created in Runtime

Tags: c#

I want to get SUM of numbers entered in textboxes which created in runtime. 
im new to C# and here is the code, i think you can get idea about what i need.
Thank you.

**need to get sum of value entered in textboxes which created by 'TextBox[] textBoxes' array, in run time**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(txtNo.Text); // value entered in "txtNO" text box


        TextBox[] textBoxes = new TextBox[n];
        int y = 70;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            textBoxes[i] = new TextBox();
            textBoxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190, y);

            this.Controls.Add(textBoxes[i]);
            y += 30;

        }

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Statement Textboxes Sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992590/c-sharp-statement-textboxes-sum)

Comment: And what is not working? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not exactly @Sine. The error on the reference was due to the formatting issues. This question directs to dynamic property access.

Answer (score -1):

```
int sum = 0;
foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if((ctrl as TextBox) != null)
    {
        TextBox txt = ctrl as TextBox;
        int val = int.Parse(txt.Text);
        sum += val;
    }
}
```

Comment: David, I tried to comment on your post, but it was deleted. Your code works only and only if all controls are TextBoxes. Please review your answer to exclude other types. as  this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Text));

Comment: @ user3021830, Your code works only and only if all texts in the TextBoxes are integers. If it is float, it won't work! Note that I just follow your comment's logic, which I think it rediculous. but you are just doing that! How do you feel? :)

Comment: You think just trying to get the Text property of all Forms controls is fine, go ahead. But just be mature. This site is not for revenge of for personal satisfaction. I downvoted, because you were handling all controls as TextBoxes which is fatal.

Comment: You think just trying to assume all the Texts are of integer types, it is fine, go ahead. But just be mature. This site is not for revenge of for personal satisfaction. I downvoted, because you were handling all texts as integers which is fatal for texts such as 3.14. Love to continue this sort of comments if you continue. I just follow your suit, laugh, :)